# "same as last month" or "same as last month's"?

Tags: tenses

> "X was the only item having the same score as last month"

> "X was the only item having same score as last month's"

Which of the above sentences makes sense?

Comment: Ask yourself: "*as last month's **<what>**?*"  and then think about, "*...only item having the same score as **[it had]** last month.*"

Comment: @Jim Nice comment!